# Recursive indexing only works up to [[1:3]]

Tags: r, recursion, indexing

I need to refer to individual dataframes within a list of dataframes (one by one) produced from a lapply function, but I'm getting the "recursive indexing failed at level 3" error. I've found similar questions, but none of them explain why this doesn't work.

I used lapply to make a list of dataframes, each with a different filter applied. The output in my reproducible example has 4 dataframes in the output (dfs). Now I want to refer to each dataframe in turn by indexing its position in the list.

If I use the format `c(dfs[[1]], dfs[[2]], dfs[[3]], dfs[[4]])` I get the output that I want, and it works for the next function I need to apply, but it seems very inefficient.

When I try to shorten it by using `c(dfs[[1:4]])` instead, I get the error `Error in data1[[1:4]] : recursive indexing failed at level 3`. If I try `c(dfs[[1:3]])`, it runs, bit doesn't give the output I expect (no longer a list of dataframes).

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse) # for glimpse, filter, mutate
data(mtcars)

mtcars2 <- mutate(mtcars, var = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), len = 32)) # need a variable with more than 3 possible outcomes
glimpse(mtcars2)

list <- c("A", "B", "C", "D") # each new dataframe will filter based on these variables

dfs <- lapply(list, function(x) {
  mtcars2 %>% filter(var == x) %>% glimpse()
}) # each dataframe now only contains A, B, C, or D

dfs # list of dataframes produced from lapply

dflist1 <- list(dfs[[1]], dfs[[2]], dfs[[3]], dfs[[4]]) # indexing one by one
dflist1 # this is what I want

dflist2 <- list(dfs[[1:4]]) # indexing all together
dflist2 # this produces an error

dflist3 <- list(dfs[[1:3]])
dflist3 # this runs, but the output is just `[[1]] [1] 4`, not a list of dataframes
```

I want something that looks like the output from `dflist1` but that doesn't require me to add and remove list items every time the number of dataframes changes. I can't use the lapply output (`dfs`) as it is because my next function can't locate the variables within each dataframe as needed.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: You say you want the output like `dflist1`, but you can't use `dfs`? From what I can see these are the same objects?

Comment: `\`[[\`` can only take a single index, because it extracts the element from the structure. To use multiple indices and keep the structure, use `\`[\``.

Comment: @SymbolixAU the next thing I have to do is make linear models for each dataframe, but if I use the original `dflist1` output, it can't locate the variable names within the dataframe. When I use `dflist2`, it can. Not sure why.

edit: this is actually the same problem as when I use `dfs[1:9]`

Comment: @alistaire That worked, thank you for taking the time to reply!

Comment: [this is a useful reference](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/643381054758363136) about indexing lists

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but are you familiar with nested dataframes? Check out chapter 25 in this book (R for Data Science, by Hadley); it made my life a lot easier:

https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#gapminder

Comment: @djfinnoy That is incredibly useful for what I'm trying to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MirandaChilver Happy to help, I recommend reading that book cover to cover, it's pure gold.